# "a synonym of" vs. "a synonym for"

Tags: prepositions

I understand the meaning of "synonym", I'm just not sure of its usage, in particular the correct preposition follows it.

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/synonym)

> Cool is not **a synonym for** all things good.

Which indicates "a synonym for" is a correct use.

Ngram Viewers shows "a synonym of" could also be a correct use.

[image]

Does this mean the same thing as the quotation?

> Cool is not **a synonym of** all things good.

Comment: `Of` and `for` are both OK and are shown in Cambridge Dictionary examples of usage. `synonym of ingestion` and `synonym for craft`.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you. Presumably, `synonym of ingestion` sounds natural to native English speakers. Does `synonym for ingestion` also sound natural and mean the same thing?

Comment: Both are OK, as I indicated.

Comment: "Synonym of" always refers to words. "Synonym for" and "synonymous with" can also have an extended meaning, eg "Rolls-Royce is a synonym for luxury in automobiles" or "Oscar Wilde is synonymous with wit".

Answer (score 2):

"Synonym of" always refers to words. "Synonym for" and "synonymous with" often refer to words, but they can also have an extended meaning. For example "Rolls-Royce is a synonym for luxury in automobiles" or "Oscar Wilde is synonymous with wit".